# Accessing column in sparse CSR matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Having some issues with accessing the last column in the sparse CSR matrix. Ideally, I would like to convert the last column into some sort of array that can be used as my label set. My CSR matrix looks like this:

```
(0, 1976)   1
  (0, 2916) 1
  (0, 3871) 1
  (0, 4437) 1
  (0, 8202) 1
  (0, 9458) 1
  (0, 10597)    1
  (1, 4801) 1
  (1, 6903) 1
  (1, 7525) 1
  (2, 873)  1
  (2, 1017) 1
  (2, 1740) 1
  (2, 1925) 1
  (3, 1976) 1
  (3, 5606) 1
  (3, 6898) 1
```

I want to access the last column, which contains all the '1'. Is there a way in which I can do this?

Comment: Try `my_matrix.data`.

Comment: Normally, if someone asked for the last column of a sparse matrix `A`, I would say use regular indexing: `A[:, -1]`.  Is that not what you want?  Can you give a small but complete example with, say, a 4x8 matrix (instead of one with thousands of columns) that shows exactly what you want?

Comment: What you show is the `coo` style **display** of nonzero indices and values.  The values, or `data` are all 1, but I would not describe that a the "last column" of a matrix.  But even `A[:,-1]` doesn't make sense as a "label set".  It will just be an array of 0s with just a few ones (maybe only one).  You need a better understanding of what your matrix represents.

Answer (score 0):

CSR matrix has `indicies` and `indptr` properties, see below example which converts matrix to list using these properties:

```
def sparse_to_string_list(matrix: csr_matrix):
    res = []
    indptr = matrix.indptr
    indices = matrix.indices
    for row in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        arr = [k for k in indices[indptr[row]: indptr[row + 1]]]
        arr.sort()
        res.append(' '.join([str(k) for k in arr]))
    return res
```

Comment: Thanks Zaven. However, it seems that this does not exactly produce the result I'm looking for. I only want the last column which is the column that has all the 1s.

Comment: Now what I'm getting is matrix[0] = [1976, 2916, 3871, ..., 10597]. However, I am looking for [1, 1, 1, ... 1] instead. How can I do this?

Comment: Also, is there a way to convert to string list into an integer list instead?